# Matlab figure keeps the history of the previous images

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am working on rotating image manually in Matlab. Each time I run my code with a different image the previous images which are rotated are shown in the Figure. I couldn't figure it out. Any help would be appreciable.
The code is here:

[image][screenshot]

```
im1 = imread('gradient.jpg');

[h, w, p] = size(im1);
theta = pi/12;
hh = round( h*cos(theta) + w*abs(sin(theta)));      %Round to nearest integer
ww = round( w*cos(theta) + h*abs(sin(theta)));      %Round to nearest integer

R = [cos(theta) -sin(theta); sin(theta) cos(theta)];
T = [w/2; h/2];
RT = [inv(R) T; 0 0 1];
for z = 1:p
for x = 1:ww
    for y = 1:hh
        % Using matrix multiplication
        i = zeros(3,1);
        i = RT*[x-ww/2; y-hh/2; 1];


        %% Nearest Neighbour
        i = round(i);
        if i(1)>0 && i(2)>0 && i(1)<=w && i(2)<=h
            im2(y,x,z) = im1(i(2),i(1),z);
        end
    end
end
end



 x=1:ww;
 y=1:hh;

 [X, Y] = meshgrid(x,y);      %  Generate X and Y arrays for 3-D plots
 orig_pos = [X(:)' ; Y(:)' ; ones(1,numel(X))];   %  Number of elements in array or   subscripted array expression
 orig_pos_2 = [X(:)'-(ww/2) ; Y(:)'-(hh/2) ; ones(1,numel(X))];

 new_pos = round(RT*orig_pos_2); % Round to nearest neighbour

 % Check if new positions fall from map:
 valid_pos = new_pos(1,:)>=1 & new_pos(1,:)<=w & new_pos(2,:)>=1 & new_pos(2,:)<=h;

 orig_pos = orig_pos(:,valid_pos);
 new_pos = new_pos(:,valid_pos);

 siz = size(im1);
 siz2 = size(im2);

%  Expand the 2D indices to include the third dimension.
 ind_orig_pos = sub2ind(siz2,orig_pos(2*ones(p,1),:),orig_pos(ones(p,1),:), (1:p)'*ones(1,length(orig_pos)));
 ind_new_pos  = sub2ind(siz, new_pos(2*ones(p,1),:), new_pos(ones(p,1),:), (1:p)'*ones(1,length(new_pos)));

 im2(ind_orig_pos) = im1(ind_new_pos);
  imshow(im2);
```

Comment: Have you tried using `cla` each time you start a new image plot?

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't solve the problem unfortunately.

Comment: @RuhiAkaboy Do you have multiple figures open; if so you need to bring the figure of interest into focus. Also, do you have a `hold on` anywhere in your code? If you do, you need to place a `hold off` after you're done placing an image.

Comment: I dont use 'hold on' in my code. I read only one image when I run the code as you see in the code.

Comment: Can anyone just copy the whole code and run on his computer in Matlab? The code is error-free actually. You wont get compiling errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with the initialization of `im2`, or rather, the lack of it. `im2` is created in the section shown below:

```
if i(1)>0 && i(2)>0 && i(1)<=w && i(2)<=h
    im2(y,x,z) = im1(i(2),i(1),z);
end
```

If `im2` exists before this code is run and its width or height is larger than the image you are generating the new image will only overwrite the top left corner of your existing `im2`. Try initializing `im2` by adding adding

```
im2 = zeros(hh, ww, p);
```

before

```
for z = 1:p
    for x = 1:ww
        for y = 1:hh
             ...
```

As a bonus it might make your code a little faster since Matlab won't have to resize `im2` as it grows in the loop.

Comment: yea actually i didn't initialize `im2` before I used it. Thanks @erikced